# How does downloading game updates works?

Tags: java, android

Let's say I published a game and after some point of time I wanted to release an all new feature for the game. Of course the app must be able recognize and download the update. How does this work specifically with Google Play apps? Does the app download the entire new version of APK from the market and reinstalls itself? I'm using Java for the development, if this info helps. Any tips you can give me about this topic?

Answer (score 1):

With Google Play, the user is notified that app updates are available. It is up to the user to initiate the download of the updates.

You can always include in your app a check to your server as to whether an update is available. However, this becomes a maintenance issue.